# css label width not taking effect

Tags: html, css, label

I have a generic form, which I'd like to style to align the labels and the input fields.
For some reason when I give a width to the label selector, nothing happens:

HTML:

```
<form id="report-upload-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <label for="id_title">Title:</label> 
        <input id="id_title" type="text" class="input-text" name="title"></p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_description">Description:</label> 
        <textarea id="id_description" rows="10" cols="40" name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p>
        <label for="id_report">Upload Report:</label> 
        <input id="id_report" type="file" class="input-file" name="report">
    </p>
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
#report-upload-form {
    background-color: #316091;
    color: #ddeff1;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 23px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    width: 650px;
    box-shadow:  0 0 2px 2px #d9d9d9;
}

#report-upload-form label {
    padding-left:26px;
    width:125px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#report-upload-form input[type=text], 
#report-upload-form input[type=file],
#report-upload-form textarea {
    width: 305px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL0tnhr9/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, is wrapping the form sections in `<p>` tags really a good idea?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Do `display: inline-block`:

```css
#report-upload-form label {
    padding-left:26px;
    width:125px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqMN4/

Comment: Stick with Inline-block. Tested it in IE7,IE8,IE9, FF

Comment: Is there a workaround to placing each element in a <p>?

Comment: @ColinD I would recommend using divs, not <p> tags.

Answer (score 45):

Use `display: inline-block;`

**Explanation:**

The `label` is an inline element, meaning it is only as big as it needs to be.

Set the `display` property to either `inline-block` or `block` in order for the `width` property to take effect.

**Example:**

```css
#report-upload-form {
    background-color: #316091;
    color: #ddeff1;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 23px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 650px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #d9d9d9;

}

#report-upload-form label {
    padding-left: 26px;
    width: 125px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}

#report-upload-form input[type=text], 
#report-upload-form input[type=file],
#report-upload-form textarea {
    width: 305px;
}
```

```html
<form id="report-upload-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input id="id_title" type="text" class="input-text" name="title"></p>
    <p><label for="id_description">Description:</label> <textarea id="id_description" rows="10" cols="40" name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="id_report">Upload Report:</label> <input id="id_report" type="file" class="input-file" name="report"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! inline-block is what I needed. Block makes it look weird.

Comment: Be aware that inline-block's support is sketchy in IE below IE8 - probably not too much of a problem these days, but something to keep in mind. (source http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Comment: @PandaWood Sorry it's almost 2 years since you commented on this post. But, I am replying to your comment so that other readers are not misguided by the explanation given by the author of this post. The latter has reasoned that the `label` element doesn't respect the `width` property because it's an inline element. I would like to point out that the `input` element is also an inline element by default. But it allows its width to be changed using the width property unlike the `label` element. Hence the reasoning by the author is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

I believe labels are inline, and so they don't take a width. Maybe try using "display: block" and going from there.

Answer (score 6):

Make it a block first, then float left to stop pushing the next block in to a new line.

```css
#report-upload-form label {
                           padding-left:26px;
                           width:125px;
                           text-transform: uppercase;
                           display:block;
                           float:left
}
```

Answer (score 5):

give the style

```
display:inline-block;
```

hope this will help'

Answer (score 4):

`label`'s default `display` mode is `inline`, which means it automatically sizes itself to it's content. To set a width you'll need to set `display:block` and then do some faffing to get it positioned correctly (probably involving `float`)

Answer (score 1):

```
   label
    {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

will give you the flexibility to change the width of the labels and custom align the form. cheers